# Html links read on smartphone

Tags: html, css, email, hyperlink, smartphone

I have an issue with smartphones. When reading an email on a smartphone the pictures with a link on them are shifted to the right. There is a white space to the left of the image. Only on those who contain a url.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? How cand i resolve it? I've set all paddings and margins to 0, borders to 0....what else could I try?

```
{
    display:block;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    outline:0;
    border;0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can just do `margin:0px` and `padding:0px`. No need to do left, right, bottom etc as it covers them all.

Comment: Are these images contained within `a` elements? And have you checked for `text-indent`, `padding`, `borders` (transparent or otherwise), `font-size` (and so on) on those?

Comment: It's probably not causing it, but I don't like seeing it, your border property is formatted incorrectly with the ';' instead of ':'.

Comment: If you take the HTML content of the e-mail, and view it in e.g. Chrome on a PC, do you see the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's an issue with your CSS border declaration, it should be:

```css
border: 0;
```

You also don't need to declare each padding/margin edge individually, you can just as easily use:

```css
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

I expect that you're seeing this due to styling in the parent anchor rather than the image itself.  You could try the following (although this is a bit of a blanket reset-all; you probably won't need all of this):

```js
a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    border: 0 none;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

If you like, put up a snippet of your code where you can replicate this issue and we can take a more in-depth look?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the CSS inline on your image tag. You can also trim down your CSS a fair bit.

Here is all you need for a linked image in html email:

```
<a href=""><img alt="" src="" width="" height="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"></a>
```

If your gap still exists, it is because of the parent element, or some other CSS you have on the a or image tag. It is good practice in html-email to keep each image in it's own `<td>`. Placing the above tag in it's own table cell will work perfectly.

Also, add this to your [header style tag for Outlook](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/):

```
#outlook a {padding:0;}
```